# How to change a PictureBox image from another Form

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I want to open `form2` while `form1` loads. Also, I want to change the Image of a PictureBox in `form2` when an action is triggered in `form1`.

To open `form2` while `form1` loads I used this code:

```
private void MONITOR3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MONITOR4 mo4 = new MONITOR4(this);
    mo4.Show();
}
```

To change the Image of the PictureBox in `form2` I used this code, which is must to be run after a condition is met:

```
if (textBox1.Text == @"QUEBEC - ALPHA - TANGO - ALPHA - ROMEO - ")
{
    MONITOR4 mo4 = new MONITOR4(this);
    mo4.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:/QResources/images/HIA.jpg");
}
```

Comment: You can keep th first snippet as reference and eliminate the other two, they're wrong. You should instead show what action in `Form1` triggers the change in `Form2`.

Comment: i didn't get you

Comment: I meant you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53897347/edit), leaving the first code snippet (`private void MONITOR3_Load (...)` etc.) which shows your intention. The other two snippets are not useful because are wrong. Then, you said you want to *change the image in the pictureBox in form2 depending on an action that happens in form1*. You should show when/where this *action* is performed and what it is. This is the important part that needs to be added to your question.

Comment: So what is wrong with your code, what errors do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your current code:

- You don't have to create a new Form instance each time you need to set some of its properties: store a reference to this Form and use this reference to call public properties or methods of the Form.
- You are trying to directly access a child Control's properties of another Form. Event though you can define a child Control `public`, you shouldn't and it's not necessary. A Form is a class like any other in this aspect: create a public method on the Form that provides means to modify a private property, without directly exposing a Control's property to direct access.
  It's simple, safer and more *portable*: if a Control needs to be modified (the name is changed, the type of Control is changed etc.), you don't need to go on a hunt to find where the old name/properties have been used in other classes.
  The public method will be the same and it's the only responsible to reference the current names, properties of the affected Control. A single place where the code, eventually, needs to be modified.
  You could also use a public event or implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) to notify the subscribers that some properties have changed.

Here, I'm creating a reference to `Monitor4` in the `Monitor3` Form:

```
Monitor4 mo4 = null;
```

This reference will be use to call a public method (`UpdatePictureBox`) of `Monitor4`.

`Monitor3` Form:
(I'm using the `TextChanged` event of a TextBox to select the Image to show in the `Monitor4` PictureBox. Of course, it could be the `Validate` event or anything else that agrees with your design)

```
public partial class Monitor3 : Form
{
    Monitor4 mo4 = null;

    private void Monitor3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mo4 = new Monitor4();
        //Show Monitor4 on the right side of this Form
        mo4.Location = new Point(this.Right + 10, this.Top);
        mo4.Show(this);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string newText = textBox1.Text;
        switch (newText) {
            case "[Some text 1]":
                mo4.UpdatePictureBox(@"[Images1 Path]");
                break;
            case "QUEBEC - ALPHA - TANGO - ALPHA - ROMEO - ":
                mo4.UpdatePictureBox(@"[Images2 Path]");
                break;
            case "[Some text 3]":
                mo4.UpdatePictureBox(@"[Images3 Path]");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

`Monitor4` Form:

```
public partial class Monitor4 : Form
{
    public void UpdatePictureBox(string imagePath)
    {
        if (File.Exists(imagePath)) {
            pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(imagePath, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample result:

[image: Access a Form's Control from another class]